# QT Creator remote connection

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator

I'm using QT Creator to develop an application to run as embeded on Linux S.O. (without  graphical interface). Now I would like manage this application remotely ( like a team viewer ), create another application to send updates from my PC to everywhere.
Has anyone already did something like it or has any ideia how can I do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please try to ask concrete questions. Use your favorite search engine, try something yourself and ask a question when you encounter a problem.

Comment: good question !